# PHP ternary inside concatenation with no else?

Tags: php, string, concatenation, ternary-operator, ternary

I want to check if 2 variables are the same and if so, echo a string. Is this possible within a concatenation? And to do it without creating a separate function?

e.g.

`$var = 'here is the first part and '. ( $foo == $bar ) ? "the optional middle part" .' and the rest of the string.'`

**EDIT**

Note, I'm looking to see if there is a way to do it *without* the `: ''`. A "binary operator" if you will.

Comment: Yes, the e.g. above doesn't work.

Comment: you cannot use ternary statement without `:` part. why you don't want to use it?

Comment: It's superfluous—just looking to shorten things up. And sate my OCD.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't try to shorten things up too much. You need that `: ''` in order for things to work.

Use `(condition) ? "show when true" : ""` to display an optional text depending on the condition. A ternary operator is named that way because it consists of 3 parts.

```
$var = 'here is the first part and '. (( $foo == $bar ) ? "the optional middle part" : "") .' and the rest of the string.';
```

Comment: well, you were few sec quicker.

Comment: @MarkoD But the OP actually changed the question to say "without the `: ''`".

Comment: Thanks. I kinda knew this before I posted but hopefully this will help others avoid years of never finding a definite answer.

Comment: I still wish there was a 'binary operator' for if only. :)

Comment: @AndrewTibbetts If you like "binary operator": `$var = 'here is the first part and '; $foo !== $bar || $var.= "the optional middle part"; $var .=' and the rest of the string.';` This doesn't really shorten things up at all.

Comment: My brother had the idea to create a function: `function concatenable_if ($statement, $value) { if ($statement) return $value; else return ''; }` but again, I was looking for something built into php.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "Can I do it without the colon and empty quotes?" The answer is no you cannot. You must have the closing `:''` and it is best to use paren's to clarify your desires.

```
$var = 'here is the first part and '. 
        (( $foo == $bar ) ? "the optional middle part":'') .
       ' and the rest of the string.'
```

I think the biggest problem here is that you're trying to do things inline. This basically boils down to the same process and does not use an unclosed ternary:

```
$var = 'here is the first part and ';
if( $foo == $bar ) $var .= "the optional middle part";
$var .= ' and the rest of the string.';
```

Whereas this is another way to accomplish the same goal without needing to worry about conditionals breaking the string:

```
$middle = '';
if( $foo == $bar ) $middle = ' the optional middle part and';
$var = sprintf('here is the first part and%s the rest of the string.',$middle);
```

Now, if you are going to be needlessly clever, I suppose you could do this instead:

```
$arr = array('here is the first part and',
             '', // array filter will remove this part
             'here is the end');
// TRUE evaluates to the key 1. 
$arr[$foo == $bar] = 'here is the middle and';
$var = implode(' ', array_filter($arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

ternary operator syntex is as follows

```
(any condition)?"return this when condition return true":"return this when condition return false"
```

so in your string it should be like this

```
$var = 'here is the first part and '.( ( $foo == $bar ) ? "the optional middle part":"") .' and the rest of the string.'
```

which means your conditions is missing else past and operator precedence